# selenium: element which not visible?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I tried this xpath but I don't know how to continue ? the element isn't visible at all

the html of the page is:

```
<form id="form-resetpass" method="post" action="">
    <div class="input-wrapper icon wupid">
    <label for="wupid">תעודת זהות</label>
    <input class="only-numbers ltr" type="text" value="" maxlength="9" name="wupid" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: left center;">
    </div>
    <input class="sprite form-resetpass" type="submit" value="" name="">
    <div class="form-error"> </div>
    </form>
```

the java code:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='only-numbers ltr']")));
```

try also this code: and the same error

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='only-numbers ltr' and @name='wupid']")).sendKeys("111");
```

After execution of code I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed
>   out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by
>   By.xpath: //input[@class='only-numbers ltr']

also try/check:
maximize the current window that webdriver is using (e.g. maximize()).

the element is not hidden.

that is the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure the class not change during test? Try `//input[@name='wupid']`. Can you find the element manually (for example in firepath)?

Comment: If you have an id for the form is a good practice to start from there with the selector. Check if the selector finds multiple elements or not and if it is contained in an iframe. You can also use a simple css like: #form-resetpass input[name=wupid]

Comment: Can you please share the URL, so we can give it a try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium: element is not visible using cssSelector while visible using xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179537/selenium-element-is-not-visible-using-cssselector-while-visible-using-xpath)